# How to Deserialize using GSON?

Tags: android, json, gson

How to deserialize the following response from server using GSON in Android?
I want to deserialize the following code and store the data in a java class instance using JsonReader.

```
{
   "createTimestamp": "2013-05-23 09:39:41",
   "firstName": "ABCD",
   "lastName": "EFGH",
   "mediaListResponse":
   [
       {
           "mediaTitle": "Media Title",
           "createTimestamp": null,
           "mediaId": 120,
           "mediaUrl": "/img/mediadata/46/420/1/230.jpg",
           "authenticationKey": null,
           "responseCode": null,
           "responseMessage": null
       },
       {
           "mediaTitle": "Media Title",
           "createTimestamp": null,
           "mediaId": 120,
           "mediaUrl": "/img/mediadata/46/420/1/230.jpg",
           "authenticationKey": null,
           "responseCode": null,
           "responseMessage": null
       }
   ],
   "authenticationKey": null,
   "responseCode": "200",
   "responseMessage": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create java object classes corresponding to the json input, e.g.

```
   class YourObject {
    String createTimestamp;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    List<MediaListItem> mediaListResponse;
   [...] 
  }

  class MediaListItem {
     String mediaTitle;
     String createTimestamp;
     int mediaId;
     [...]
  }
```

The you can use the objects to hold your parsed json objects. I do it like this:

**UPDATE:**

For single json object:

```
       YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourObject.class);
```

For array of json objects:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(jsonMetaData).getAsJsonArray();
        ArrayList<MyObject> parsedObj = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        // Add each parsed elements from the Jarray to your object structure
        for (JsonElement obj : Jarray)
        {
            MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(obj, MyObject.class);
            parsedObj.add(obj);
        }
```

Comment: didn't understood the  for (JsonElement obj : Jarray)
        {
            MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(obj, MyObject.class);
            parsedObj.add(obj);
        } part..........What is MyObject here?

Comment: Ok that part might be "overkill" for your purpose. It collects multiple objects, if you have an array of parsed objects. It seems that you only expect one object so YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObj.class); is sufficient for you. I recommend you to have a look at the examples on the gson page https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide . It helped me when i started with GSON. If you want, i can post another example for you.

Comment: Your welcome :) If my answer was helpful for you please mark on the leftside as solved with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote with a detailed explanation on how to parse `JSON` file in android with the native tools and the `GSON` library:

[JSON Parsing](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)

in few short steps:

**1.**  You will need to create a class that will represent you parsed JSON data.

**2.**  Set the names of the variables in this class to match those of the parsed data or use annotation to specify the correct names.

**3.** Finaly you will use a command like this one to parse the data:

```
Student student = gson.fromJson(currentStudent.toString(), Student.class);
```

all those steps are explained in the guide in great detail.

Good luck.